# How to estimate the current driven by this uC board for this operation?

Tags: microcontroller, power, current

I want to power [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105823-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf) uC board through its E5V power input pin as shown in below table:

[image]

The power source for the E5V pin will be the +5V Vcc pin of [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/588e/0900766b80d4cba6.pdf) FTDI converter. And in its datasheet the following specs are given:

[image]

I will interface the uC board only with the FTDI converter, meaning that I will not use any other pins of the uC board besides FTDI's RX TX Vcc and GND. In this case, how can we make assumption whether using the FTDI converter's Vcc to power the IC board is within the limits of safe operation?

Comment: "meaning that I will not use any other pins of the uC board besides..." Is that when the application goes live or during development? Because during development you'll want to supply the in-circuit debugger and the FTDI adapter can't manage that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know the answer already.

Compare the minimum voltage **provided** by the FTDI and the minimum voltage **required** by the microcontroller board. You can not be sure they will work together.